# Specifics about the definition of compact support

Tags: real-analysis

When considering the space $X=C_{0}[0,\infty)$ we know that the space of continuous functions with compact support is dense in $X$.  Let $f$ be continuous with compact support. By definition compact support means that $f$ is zero outside of some compact set or in this case a closed and bounded interval in $[0,\infty)$. My question is about what happens with $f$ between an endpoint and where it eventually becomes zero. Are we just assuming that you can extend $f$ to $0$ outside of its support so that it remains continuous?

Comment: I think you are incorrectly interpreting what is a compact set. It need not be a closed and bounded *interval*, but a closed and bounded *set*. We are saying that $f$ *is identically zero* on the complement of this compact set. Also, since $f$ is continuous you can see that $f$ is also zero on the boundary points of this compact set.

Comment: You're right I was not interpreting compact correctly. I oversimplified what compact on $[0,\infty)$ means. That last sentence helps a lot too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is defined on all of $X$, but there is a compact $K$ such that $f(x)=0$ for all $x \notin K$. There is no need to extend anything, the function is already defined everywhere from the start. The only extension that's relevant is that we can define $f(\infty)=0$ too (where $\infty$ is the added point in the one-point compactification $\alpha X$) and be assured that the extended map to the larger $\alpha X$ is indeed continuous when $f$ was on $X$ (with compact support).